# To redirect page in javascript with value

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect page alongwith value. I think I have used the right syntax. But for some reason it is not working. I am getting the value also but my page seems to being refreshed. I have taken field name 'content' and used function submitform12

```
HTML :
<textarea name="content" id="content" cols="" rows="" class="txt-input"></textarea>
<a href="" onclick="return submitform12()">Redirect</a>

Javascript :
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform12()
{
    var status = document.getElementById('content');
    if(status.value == "")
    {
    alert("Please share your thoughts.");
    status.focus();
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    window.location.href    = "wallpostaction.php?content="+status.value;
    return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: In the else statement, you are not returning anything.

Comment: not a good idea to pass it in query string as query string has a limit defined by browser vendor. Why don't you POST to that page and on success you redirect to some other page?

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle he may not need to return anything. No rule says that if statement return something and hence else should

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle I have tried that one also but not succeeded

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal He is calling return submitform12() though.

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle no rule specifies that all the code paths return value

Comment: yeah i will definitely try that one also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `#` in your `href`

```
<a href="#" onclick="return submitform12()">Redirect</a>
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QNLjE/6/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. You can solve either way.

You can make the clicking of the anchor moot by adding `#` to the href or void it via javascript.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return submitform12()">Redirect</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return submitform12()">Redirect</a>
```

The latter of the two is better if your application is sensitive to hashes.

Or you can always return false from your onclick.

```
else
{
window.location.href    = "wallpostaction.php?content="+status.value;
return false;  //  <----------- ALWAYS return false.
}
```

Returning true will cause the browser to act on the anchor whereas returning false for onclick make it do nothing.